# how do I change the directory of the android virtual device?

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, virtual, device

I am using Mac OS X, and Eclipse IDE, and when I try to run a sample project, i.e. Snake etc, I cannot access my newly made Android Virtual Device because it was saved to another directory, and not within my workspace, to the best of my understanding.

I tried to modify the run configurations for my project, but cannot detect the AVD because it is in another directory, and I cannot figure how to change this directory and run my sample application.

I am just starting android development, and I cannot even run a sample app. :-( I installed the necessary plug-in and all the necessary packages.

Comment: I have read a little about this error online, and I think I need to move the directory to my Android folder, but I also need to create a new environment variable. How do I do this on a Mac?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse got to Window -> AVD Manager. What do you see there? There is no option to choose a directory to store an AVD and it is not stored within your workspace. If you installed everything correctly you should be able to configure an AVD here in AVD Manager and it will be seen by your Android Project at Run or Debug time. Make sure the API level is correct in the AVD.

Comment: Where does Eclipse look for the AVD's? I created an AVD, but it was saved into my user directory on my Mac, so when I go to run my sample code, it doesn't see that there are any AVD's available.